# Get fundamental discriminant

Tags: python, sage

Is there a function in Sage which returns the fundamental discriminant associated to a given discriminant?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_discriminant

This is the function I wrote, not finding an existing one:

```
def getFund(D):
    if D % 4 == 2 or D % 4 == 3:
        raise ValueError("Not a discriminant.")
    if D == 0:
        raise ValueError("There is no fundamental associated to 0.")
    P = sign(D)
    for p in factor(D):
        if p[1] % 2 == 1:
            P *= p[0]
    if P % 4 == 2 or P % 4 == 3:
        P *= 4
    return P
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem with fundamental_discriminant?

```
sage: fundamental_discriminant(1)
1
sage: fundamental_discriminant(3)
12
sage: fundamental_discriminant?
Signature:      fundamental_discriminant(D)
Docstring:
   Return the discriminant of the quadratic extension K=Q(sqrt{D}),
   i.e. an integer d congruent to either 0 or 1, mod 4, and such that,
   at most, the only square dividing it is 4.

   INPUT:

   * "D" - an integer

   OUTPUT:

   * an integer, the fundamental discriminant
```

Comment: I think there is no problem. Thank you for mentioning the method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the function is implemented in SageMath.

But if I understand the definition correctly, you can define the function as follows:

```
def fundamental_discriminant(d):
    if d % 4 == 1:
        return d.squarefree_part()
    if d % 4 == 0:
        k = d.valuation(4)
        dd = d // 4^k
        if dd % 4 == 1:
            return dd.squarefree_part()
        if dd % 4 == 2:
            return 4 * dd.squarefree_part()
        if dd % 4 == 3:
            return 4 * dd.squarefree_part()
    raise ValueError("Not a discriminant.")
```

Comment: Thanks. I also wrote an own implementation since I didn't get an answer here in the first few hours. I'll add it to my question. Does a//b mean floor(a/b)?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain -- Exactly: in Python `a // b` is the quotient in the "quotient and remainder" division, and `a % b` is the remainder. In Sage one can get both at once with `quo_rem`, for example `23.quo_rem(7)` gives `(3, 2)`, and indeed `23 = 3 * 7 + 2`.